# Collabora Online: discovery.xml from “https://example.com” is not a well-formed XML string

Tags: libreoffice, owncloud

I have installed collabora online on my VPS server through owncloud now it's shows the error : Collabora Online: discovery.xml from “https://example.com” is not a well-formed XML string.
Please contact the “https://example.com” administrator.